# Gitで正常にファイルをpush出来ません。

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

下記のコマンドでHTMLファイルを編集、GitHubへ変更をpushしようとしたのですが、アウトプットが `0 insertions`になりGitHub上には空のファイルがアップロードされてしまいました。

```
$ touch hello.html
$ atom .
$ git add -N hello.html
$ git commit -m "created hello.html"
[master a189f02] created hello.html
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .DS_Store
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atomエディタでの編集後、**ファイルを保存**してから`git add`を実行してください。

キャプチャ画像ではタブに青丸の印が付いているかと思いますが、未保存の場合に表示されるようです。

Comment: 無事解決することが出来ました。ありがとうございました！